# Format output date using date-fns with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, format, date-fns

Can you guys help with a custom format output using date-fns react library?

I'm trying to format this date '2022-01-24T05:26:28+0000' to '24 jan 2022, às 02:26', but the 's' is for second, so the output is something like this '24 jan 2022, à28 02:26'
Is there a way to prevent the 's' to format?

My code:

```
{format(
    new Date(post.data.last_publication_date),
    `PP, às p`,
    { locale: ptBR }
)}
```

I already tried using template literals such as `` ${`PP, às p`} ``, but it didn't help.

I'm using ReactJs and NextJs with this library.

Comment: You could chop it up ?

Comment: @CyrusZei I could, but I wanted to do it without slice or anything like that
I'm lookin into the documentation and if I found something I will answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I read more deep the docs from the library and they have some patterns to edit the output.

To the date '2022-01-24T05:26:28+0000' be format as '24 jan 2022, às 02:26', it requires some simple quotes, as follows:

```
`PP, 'às' p`
```

So the output will be `'24 jan 2022, às 02:26'`